# How to handle simmilar models in an API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Currently, I am developing an API that will be consumed by a mobile and a web application. A problem that I ran into is that I have too many simmilar dto models. For example, consider the following one:

```
public class DeviceModel
{
    public int DevicesID { get; set; }
    public string DeviceUID { get; set; }
    public string MACAddress { get; set; }
    public bool Allowed { get; set; }
    public UserModel Owner { get; set; }
}
```

that I use quite often. Now, I need another variation of this model that looks like this:

```
public class DeviceModelVariation
{
    public int DevicesID { get; set; }
    public string DeviceUID { get; set; }
    public string MACAddress { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best practice to handle such similar models? Is is ok to have 2 or even three such DTOs that are simmilar to each other?

Comment: You should read about OOP Inheritance, Check this link for a start https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656686.aspx#Inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create some base models that will have the common properties. The more specified models can inherit from them. Of course only in case, the properties are really common. It will also simplify the maintenance.

In your case (I would name the `DeviceModelVariation` the `DeviceModelBase` as it contains all the fields that are 'base' ones):

```
public class DeviceModelBase
{
    public int DevicesID { get; set; }
    public string DeviceUID { get; set; }
    public string MACAddress { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceModel : DeviceModelBase
{        
    public bool Allowed { get; set; }
    public UserModel Owner { get; set; }
}
```